# Exported variable 'Foo' has or is using private name 'ParentChild' in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

My code is:

```
export const Foo = <TBase>() => {
    class ParentChild {

        object: TBase;

        constructor(o: TBase) {
            this.object = o;
        }

        dump(): void {
            console.log(this.object);
        }

    }

    return ParentChild;
};
```

And I am getting an error `Exported variable 'Foo' has or is using private name 'ParentChild'.`

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

`Foo` must be a function returning a class.

Also how can I type a return type of `Foo`?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? I couldn't reproduce this error in 3.9 or 4.3. It's possible that newer versions of TS have learned how to interpolate the technically un-exported type of `class ParentChild`.

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't reproduce your error (see my comment about TS versions), the difficulty with typing `Foo`'s return suggests why the error is present. You need to export the type of the class being returned from `Foo` in order to type `Foo`'s return. Here's one approach:

```
export interface ParentChild<TBase>
{
    object: TBase;
    dump(): void;
}

export type ParentChildConstructor<TBase> = new (o: TBase) => ParentChild<TBase>;

export const Foo = <TBase>(): ParentChildConstructor<TBase> => {
    return class ParentChild {

        object: TBase;

        constructor(o: TBase) {
            this.object = o;
        }

        dump(): void {
            console.log(this.object);
        }

    }
};
```